# Is it possible to make a Poisson Distributions without Poisson Property?

Tags: distributions

In Poisson Distribution, the amount of time you need to wait for next event does not depend on how much time you have already waited. EX: In Poisson Distribution with parameter lambda, event happens every lambda minutes ... even if have already waited 2 lambda minutes, the event will still be expected to happen lambda minutes from now ... the 2 lambda minutes already waited are not relevant.

Is it possible to make modified Poisson Distribution where the time waited actually has impact on when the event will happen? I think this is more realistic. Ex: Is it possible to do something like:

- Between Time = 0 and Time = 5: Event has Poisson( Lambda_1)
- Between Time = 5 and Time = 10: Event has Poisson (Lambda_2)
- Between Time = 10 and Time = 15: Event has Poisson (Lambda_3)
- etc

Here : Lambda_1 > Lambda_2 > Lambda_3 ....

Is it possible to make some modified Poisson Distribution where there is a fluid lambda parameter that changes as time goes on? This will make it so that the probability of event happening increases if an event has not happened in a long time.

Comment: Is this generalization enough for your problem? https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter11/11_1_4_nonhomogeneous_poisson_processes.php

Comment: In a Poisson process, the hazard function is constant (equal to the rate of the process), corresponding to an exponential distribution with the same rate.  You can change the hazard function however you wish, but if it is not constant then you get a different process: for example with a hazard function equal to $\frac1{c-t}$ where $t$ is the time since the last arrival, you get a uniform distribution on $[0,c]$ instead of an exponential distribution.

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing the Poisson distribution with the Poisson process. In the Poisson **process** the waiting time until the next arrival has a memoryless **exponential** distribution, which is a **continuous** distribution, and the number of arrivals during a specificed time interval has a **Poisson** distribution, which is a **discrete** distribution.

Often these arrivals get called "events", but I think it is preferable to avoid that word because it is prominently used for a different concept in probability theory. Hence I call them arrivals.

Certainly there are Poisson processes in which the rate of arrivals varies with time.